# ExcludeFromKnownDlls - force re-read

Tags: registry

I'm writing some software for use in a live forensics environment.  I'd like to bring along my own binaries to run on the machine, including my own libraries (DLLs) since the ones on the machine may be untrusted.  Any changes to this value are read on reboot, but I don't want to reboot the machine.  Any ideas on how to force this to be re-read by the session manager without rebooting the machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find the answer to this question, but if you have a similar problem you can use DLL redirection.  DLL redirection requires you to create a folder with the name 'appname.local' in the directory where the application resides.  So for myapp.exe I'd created a folder 'myapp.exe.local'.  This would force loading of DLLs from the directory where the application resides before using the standard search path.  Note that some DLLs (such as ntdll) can't be redirected.